# Prevent user to bypass security rules by disconnecting the device and only use cached document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following concern about my app that uses firebase's offline capabilities:

The user reads a document, then disables the device's connection. The next time he opens the app, the document is still cached and he can read the document even though he might not have permission to read this document anymore.

A concrete example would be if a user buys content and refunds it later. He could always disable the device's connection to keep the content locally even though the content was refunded already.

Now its not a problem if this happens a few times when he opens the app but to my understanding, the firestore cache is only limited by size and not duration, so he could have access to the content indefinitely, as long as he doesn't establish a connection while he's using the app.

Are there any best practices to prevent this issue?

A possible solution could look like this: Check if the device has a connection, then save the last date when the devices was connected. On every app open, we check if the last time the device was connected is over some threshold and if that is the case, wipe the cache or just show a "Establish a connection" screen. The problem this way is, "honest" users also need to reconnect regularly. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore security rules are only enforced on the server, and not on the client. Once a document has reached the client, you should assume any user on that device can access it.

If you want a different way to secure access to the content in that document, consider using another/different mechanism to protect it. From what you're describing, this might be a place to use digital rights management (DRM) software.